# Failed while loading data from data set SQLQueryDataSet

Tags: kedro

I am receiving this error:

```
DataSetError: Failed while loading data from data set SQLQueryDataSet(load_args={}, sql=select * from table)
```

when I run (within kedro jupyter notebook):

```
%reload_kedro
```

c:\users\name.virtualenvs\pipenv_kedro\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py:283:DeprecationWarning: `should_run_async` will not call `transform_cell` automatically in the future. Please pass the result to `transformed_cell` argument and any exception that happen during the transform in `preprocessing_exc_tuple` in IPython 7.17 and above.
and should_run_async(code)
2021-04-21 15:29:12,278 - kedro.framework.session.store - INFO - `read()` not implemented for `BaseSessionStore`. Assuming empty store.
2021-04-21 15:29:12,696 - root - INFO - ** Kedro project Project
2021-04-21 15:29:12,698 - root - INFO - Defined global variable `context`, `session` and `catalog`
2021-04-21 15:29:12,703 - root - INFO - Registered line magic `run_viz`

Then this:

```
catalog.list()
#['table', 'parameters']
catalog.load('table')
```

where my catalog.yml file contains:

```
table:
  type: pandas.SQLQueryDataSet
  credentials: secret
  sql: select * from table
  layer: raw
```

However, I am able to pull back the expected result when I run this (within the same kedro jupyter notebook):

```
from kedro.extras.datasets.pandas import SQLQueryDataSet

sql = "select * from table"
credentials = {
    "con": secret
}
data_set = SQLQueryDataSet(sql=sql,
                           credentials=credentials)

sql_data = data_set.load()
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: I was able to get this to work: catalog.load('table'). After removing the notebook from the repo and starting over.

Comment: I think the issue is with the notebook. For some reason stale notebooks will not run catalog.load() successfully. I have to create a new notebook in order to get this to run.

Answer (score 1):

The discrepancy I believe comes from the credentials. In your catalog you had

```
table:
  type: pandas.SQLQueryDataSet
  credentials: secret
```

but in the notebook you were testing with

```
credentials = {
    "con": secret
}
```

The value mapped in the yaml file should match to the name of an entry in `credentials.yml` so something like

```
# in catalog.yml
table:
  type: pandas.SQLQueryDataSet
  credentials: db_creds

# in credentials.yml
db_creds:
    con: secret
```

Comment: You're right. I did have a typo in posing the question. I did have db_creds in the catalog.